# In corona sdk how can I reference / specify all indexes of a spawned object on the screen?

Tags: sdk, indexing, lua, coronasdk

Hi I've been wondering this for a while and it's causing me lots of problems not knowing more about how to reference / specify all indexes of a spawned enemy on the screen at one time.

Say when my character dies I want all the enemies on the screen at that time to move away from my dead character as the screen fades out. Simply calling 'enemy1' only makes one (the last spawned I think) do as it's told.

Here is my enemy spawn script:

```
local spawnTable2 = {}

local function spawnEnemy()
enemy1 = display.newSprite( group, sheetE, sequenceData2 )
enemy1.x=math.random(100,1300)
enemy1.y=math.random(360,760)
enemy1.gravityScale = 0
enemy1:play()
enemy1.type="coin"
enemy1.objTable = spawnTable2
enemy1.index = #enemy1.objTable + 1
enemy1.myName = "enemy" .. enemy1.index
physics.addBody( enemy1, "kinematic",{ density = 0, friction = 0, bounce = 1 })
enemy1.isFixedRotation = true
enemy1.type = "enemy1"
enemy1.timer = nil
enemy1.enterFrame = moveEnemy
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",enemy1)
enemy1.objTable[enemy1.index] = enemy1
hudGroup:toFront()

return enemy1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference all objects, you would need to have two things.

1. A Counter
2. Loop

First make a counter:

```
counter = 0
```

Every time the funciton is called have a counter:

```
counter = counter + 1
```

For tables, you would do something like this:

```
spawnTable2[counter].x=math.random(100,1300)
```

Then when you want to remove the object, you would just do this:

```
display.remove(spawnTable2[counter])
```

Just keep in mind, everything you do to manipulate that object will have to be inside that function.  Good luck and hope this helps.